# Does this make sense: verifying public SSL certificate?

Tags: php, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, guzzle

i'm trying to figure out if the following case makes any sense.

**Background info**

I'm building a PHP platform that makes a lot of REST API calls via Guzzle. I really need to make sure that connections are valid so apart from API authorization, NAT firewalls and valid HTTPS/SSL connections i also want to build some checks in our application. For instance i am also validating that connections come from the valid IP subnets provided by the API service.

**The problem**

Then i started looking at the SSL certificates provided by the API services we're using. Offcourse the security is based on public/private keys and i cannot see the private keys used by this service but what i could do is make sure the public certificate(s) are still the same as the ones i could store locally.

Now i don't know if that makes any sense or not? My presumption here is that certificates for these organisations will only change once every two years. And i know that it doesn't validate anything, because i don't own the private key, but still, it is an extra check.

**Practical**

Then there is the practical side, is it even possible, using the `openssl s_client` i am able to get the certificates used by the API. But the [verify option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify) that Guzzle is providing is based on a .PEM file and that uses private keys right?

```
// Use a custom SSL certificate on disk.
$client->request('GET', '/', ['verify' => '/path/to/cert.pem']);
```

So is it even possible in Guzzle or basic CURL and would it make any sense or would that just be a false sense of security?

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

The service provider's public key allows you to do two things:

- Send encrypted data that only the service provider can decrypt and no one else.
- Once the encrypted connection is established, you know for sure that the messages sent back by the service provider originates from no one else than the service provider.

No one will ever provide their private key. That would defeat the purpose of a key being private. However, the whole idea of a certificate is to provide a public key signed by a trusted root certification authorities such as Verisign. Such trusted root authorities come pre-installed on your O.S. or are added by the system administrator.

If someone manipulates DNS so as to misguide you to connect to a fake host, the encrypted connection will not be established because the fake server will not be able to decrypt your messages as he does not have the proper private key.

You do not need to store anything. Upon connection, being presented with a certificate, you can verify the validity on the fly: as previously explained, if the certificate has been issued by a trusted root certification authority stored and trusted on your machine, you are good to go.

Comment: Oke but would it make sense to store a provider's public key and check on it for extra verification? If someone manipulates a DNS server for instance and tries to supply me with false data and they use another certificate i would know.